# Not but construction

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I say 'someone is lying not on but off the couch.'

Grammatically not + preposition + but + preposition + object is possible?

Comment: Grammatically, it's fine, though 'not on but under' might be a better example. We would say they were lying 'on the floor' rather than 'off the couch'.

Comment: or "beside the couch", if they were on the floor next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's grammatically correct, but including the couch in the statement doesn't seem to bring much benefit.  If your intent is to say they're near the couch but not on it, then I would suggest "not on but near the couch", or just "on the floor near the couch.